# What is the difference between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, definition, real-numbers

I am wondering that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^1$ are same or not. $\mathbb{R}$ is the real numbers, and $\mathbb{R}^1$ is a set of 1-tuples. I am so stucked on this. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, $\mathbb{R}^1$ is the set of all functions $f:\{1\}\to\mathbb{R}$. Since there is an obvious identification $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^1\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $\varphi(f)=f(1)$, you can implicitly use this identification to think at these sets being equal.

If you think as a $1$-tuple as "a real number with parenthesis around it", then the latter is no more than the identification $(a)\mapsto a$, and again you can think about these sets being equal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it really helped. How can I write a formal proof for this set equality?

Comment: You are welcome! It won't be a true equality (in the sense where two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal iff $A\subset B$ and $B\subset A$), but an identification $A\simeq B$ (meaning that there is a bijective map $\varphi:A\to B$ allowing to think about elements of $A$ as elements of $B$, or the opposite). There, you have to prove that the map $\varphi$ I defined is bijective: it is onto, because the map $(f_a:1\mapsto a)\in\mathbb{R}^1$ is sent to $a\in\mathbb{R}$, and it is $1-1$ since if $\varphi(f)=\varphi(g)$, then $f(1)=g(1)$, and since these functions are only defined on $\{1\}\dots$

Comment: $\dots$ they are equal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.

Comment: You are welcome, and welcome to MSE! :)

Comment: @Balloon Is $\mathbb{R}^{1}$ a field? I assume that you need the isomorphism to $\mathbb{R}$ to properly define multiplication in $\mathbb{R}^{1}$?

Comment: @crystal_math: if the target of your functions is a field, you get at least a ring structure by punctually extending the operations (namely $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ and $(f\cdot g)(x)=f(x)\cdot g(x)$). Usually what you get is not a field (as soon as you have two elements in the source of your maps, you automatically get divisors of zero), but here you can check that this multiplication directly makes $\mathbb{R}^1$ a field.

Comment: I would add that the identification $(a)\mapsto a$ is the canonical projection map and that $\{1\}$ can be replaced with any set of cardinality $1$, ie the singleton sets.